# should my POCO classes communicate with repositories, and if so- how to do it?

Tags: nhibernate, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I'm writing an ASP.Net webforms app using nHibernate. Currently I'm not using any IoC framework.

Firstly- my scenarios:

1. I don't want to allow two Employees with the same name. I would like to enable the Employee class to search for other Employee with the same name and issue an error.
2. A Department may have 1000s of Employees. I need to know exactly how many Employees each Department has. I don't want to load them all into memory, so I use a calculated property- EmployeesCount. However, this property is initialized the first time the Department object is loaded. If I add / remove employees the changes are not reflected in that property. (especially since I'm using 2nd level cache, so my object persists over multiple Session scopes)

My idea of solving these problems is to have my domain objects hold reference to the appropriate Repository objects.
I think the best solution is to have my repositories implement interfaces and use some sort of IoC container / DI mechanism.

So, in Employee I'll have:

```
if (_empRepository.GetEmployeeByName(newEmployeeName) != null) //...
```

and in Department:

```
public int EmployeesCount
  {
    get
      {
         return _departmentRepository.GetCurrentEmployeesCount(this);
      }
  }
```

my questions:

1. Which is prefferable- c'tor DI

   public Employee(IEmployeeRepository repository)

or  using an IoC container?

```
public Employee()
  {
     _empRepository = container.Resolve<IEmployeeRepository>();
  }
```

1. How to implement the desired solution? I understand that Interceptors / tuplizers is the way to go, but I couldn't really get my head around the whole thing. Is [this](http://andyhitchman.wordpress.com/2009/07/27/dependency-injection-for-nhibernate/) a good example? Also- in which namespace should I define the Interfaces, the IoC container etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The POC0-to-persistence relationship is usually uni-directional: The persistence tier knows about POCOs, but not the other way around.

The moment you make the POCO responsible for things like searching for other Employees with the same name, you make it bi-directional.  I'd be concerned about growing cycles between modules in your design.

Putting that activity in the POCO might sound like a good idea, because it helps to avoid the "anemic domain model" label, but I wouldn't do it.  I'd put those methods on persistence interfaces and let them handle it.  It's also more likely that the service in charge of fulfilling the use case would want to know about duplicate Employee names; let it do the asking and leave POCO out of the conversation.

This approach will make your testing life easier.  You'll know how painful module cycles can be when you go to test.  You'll have to drag too much machinery into the test to get it to work.

Comment: That was my conecrn as well. And concerning the employees' names example- you're probably right. But what about the EmployeesCount example? In that case, when I want to access that property, my service layer would have to do something like: var department = _repository.GetDepartment(id); /* get department from NH cache; the count property is not up-to-date */     _repository.UpdateEmployeesCount(department);        Is that really desirable?

Comment: I'd ask why the service layer has to ask the database for a number it already has so it can tell it to update itself?  This particular use case sounds off to me.  Either the database always knows how many employees are in each department OR it's a perfect time to write a trigger.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the scenario here- the employees count is used to display the number of employees in a department; it's not something that's saved in the DB (it's a calculated property which actually just does 'Count(*) from Employees ...'.). it's actually also used for some logical operations inside the Department class, but that's not really relevant here.

Answer (score 3):

i also think Pocos shouldn't know about persistance. Have you considered alternatives like

```
class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Employee> ActiveEmployees { get; set; }
}

public DepartmentMap()
{
    ...
    HasMany(d => d.ActiveEmployees)
        .KeyColumn("department_id")
        .Where("stillactiveindepartment = true")      // for example
        .ExtraLazyLoad();  // will issue an Count(*) instead of initializing collection, also other methods like Contains() issue an sql
}
```

For Employee with unique names:

1) in the service/controler: before saving a new employee issue a query which checks if an employee with same name already exists.

2) Unique Constraint in database will give an exception on save.

3) Custom interceptor in the session which hooks the save/flush event. it can throw if there is already a customer

Comment: +1 very good suggestions. I actually already use a filter in my mapping (still, number of active employees is very large..). I think delegating logic to the DB is a big no-no. Maybe an interceptor is a good idea. I haven't implemented any interceptors yet. do you have any good examples? also- if an exception is thrown on flush, wouldn't that cancel the whole save operation, even for other objects in the transaction?

Comment: @sJhonny `ExtraLazyLoad` takes care that you dont populate the collection if you only need the count. i dont understand where you see "delegating logic to the DB". It's in the mapping/your code, no sproc or the like. what kind of notification do you want if employee with the same name already exists?

Comment: about the 'ExtraLazyLoad'- I read somewhere (couldn't find it now) that not loading entities when doing Count() is an 'accidental' feature and isn't guaranteed. So i'm reluctant to use that. And I meant that letting a DB constraint handle my business rule is somewhat delegating logic to DB.

Comment: @sJhonny ok it is debateable if unique and foreign keys are business logic or not. i cant tell if extra lazy always works or not, it is working for me. i would go with 1) and have constraint in db as safety net. for interceptors google yields a lot good resources.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer mostly addresses the questions you asked, and I agree with the advice there.

For your question about accessing employee counts, look into using projections with NHibernate.  I'd put a query in your service layer (for whatever web service operation needs to get the employee count) that uses a count projection.

EDIT: Forgot you're using Services/Repositories/POCOs.  In that case, create an employee count query in the repository and invoke it from the service.

Comment: hmm.. but that would create a situation where the user of the Department class is responsible for initializing it's Count property. Meaning- just doing 'new Department();' gives you an object in an incomplete state- you have to do 'repository.Initialize(department);' to finish initializing the object. This seems to me like bad practice. isn't it?